# Exporting products with Category Names instead of IDs

Tags: product, export

I am exporting the product dataflow, and in the `category_ids` column all I have are the numeric category IDs.

The [Magento User Manual](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#store-operations/data-csv-files.html%3FTocPath%3DStore%2520Operations%7CData%2520Transfer%7C_____1) states that `Each category is entered as a path, with a forward slash (/) between each level. For example: Furniture/Living Room.`

However I cant seem to get the products to export in this way.

Can anyone help?

I am using Magento 1.9 and 1.4, same issue with both.

Comment: Is it solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImportExport is doing this. So just export all the things with

```
System > Import/Export > Export
```

and you are fine.

Comment: am using this, and getting no valid data send error, how can i solve this, in my store 25,000 products

Comment: Raise your upload limits, check google for php upload max_post... whatever the setting is :)

Comment: @  Fabian Blechschmidt :  does this is enough http://i.imgur.com/osTbWpE.png